# How do I persist M-x calls so they can be displayed in MRU order?

Tags: history-variables, m-x

I would like it if my Emacs were to save the <kbd>M</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> calls in most-recently used order and if this order could persist and grow across restarts/other sessions. I am using Helm, so I guess I should be asking about `helm-M-x`, but I thought this would be a general problem which might have a solution.

Ideally the solution would not depend on `desktop-save-mode`, but if it does I am okay with that.

---

**Edit:**
Apparently I should be using savehist as I gathered from the comments, but for some reason it is not working. It seems like my savehist file is being populated, but it is not being loaded when I start Emacs anew.

```
(setq savehist-file "~/.emacs.d/savehist")
(setq history-length t)
(setq history-delete-duplicates t)
(setq savehist-additional-variables 
                    '(savehist-minibuffer-history-variables
                      magit-read-rev-history
                      helm-M-x-input-history
                      read-expression-history
                      helm-grep-history
                      minibuffer-history
                      file-name-history
                      ido-file-history
                      evil-ex-history
                      mark-ring
                      search-ring
                      extended-command-history
                      evil-jumps-history
                      kill-ring
                      search-ring
                      regexp-search-ring
                      compile-history
                      log-edit-comment-ring
                      command-history))
(savehist-mode 1)
```

Comment: I don't know about Helm, but how is your requirement different to the way the standard history already works? (which you can persist across sessions, along with other minibuffer histories, by enabling `(savehist-mode 1)` in your init file.

Comment: Are you asking about `helm-m-x` or are you asking about `M-x` in general? The question isn't clear in this regard.

Comment: You *generally* do not need to add things to `savehist-additional-variables`.  That is only needed for variables which are not *already* being treated as a minibuffer history.  So adding ring variables is valid, but most of those `-history` suffix vars are probably not needed.  You can always do some testing with `savehist-mode` enabled (i.e. just invoke all the history-using features you are interested in) and then verify what ended up in `savehist-minibuffer-history-variables`.

Comment: What does `C-h v savehist-loaded` say after you start Emacs?  (And if that indicates that it failed to load the file, `savehist-mode` should have signaled an error.)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `savehist-mode` to do what you want, if you customize `savehist-additional-variables` to add `command-history` to it.

`M-x` puts each executed command on `command-history` as a list of the command and the arguments you (implicitly or explicitly) provided. It is not a plain minibuffer history, so it isn't handled automatically by `savehist-mode`. But if you add it to `savehist-additional-variables` then it will be saved and can later be restored.

Comment: `extended-command-history` will automatically be saved by savehist, OTOH.

Answer (score 1):

There is a smex package that among other persists all M-x calls between emacs sessions in MRU.

You can either call smex directly instead of general `execute-extended-command` or call `counsel-M-x` (ivy+counsel packages) that will use smex under the hood.

I was thinking `helm-m-x` could do the same but if not, I believe it could be extended in the similar manner.

PS, btw there is `helm-M-x-always-save-history` variable in helm, maybe it could help?

Comment: `counsel-M-x` (ivy+counsel packages) that will use smex under the hood." - I thought `counsel-M-x` is a replacement for smex, not a wrapper, no?

Comment: @npostavs On its own, `counsel-M-x` provides ivy incremental completion on top of `execute-extended-command`. Using it with `smex` adds sorting based on frequency of use.

Comment: See also `amx`, which is a more recent fork of `smex` and also supported by `counsel-M-x`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same Problem and it seems that even though `helm-M-x-input-history` is saved by savehist per default, this doesn't help showing previously executed commands when using `helm-M-x`.

Despite the above comment saying that `extended-command-history` was saved automatically by savehist, the only thing that helped me was adding `extended-command-history` to `savehist-additional-variables`.

Additionally setting `helm-M-x-always-save-history` to `t` saves every `helm-M-x` command to `extended-command-history`, even when it fails.